# What does the shift left logical single cycle datapath use?

Tags: mips

I am asked to add the shift left logical instruction to a single cycle datapath. I know I need to feed the SHAMT field to the ALU, but I'm not sure how to do this. I understand the basics of single cycle data paths for R-format, branch, load word, and store word, but I'm not sure how the SLL plays in... Can anyone help explain how a single cycle SLL datapath works?

If this is the wrong form for this post, I'd be much obliged if someone would direct me to the correct site.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to decode the opcode of the `SLL` instruction and use it to set the ALUOp input of the ALU to 11. You also need to set the multiplexers to put the source register and the shift amount at the appropriate inputs to the ALU.

Comment: So is there anything I need to add to the diagram? A mux perhaps?